# Server response to PDF form submitting

Tags: asp.net, pdf, acrobat

I have a PDF form with a submit button that http submits the pdf to an ASP.NET application. What should be the application response? I figured out that I need to send the pdf back in the output response stream. This makes the Adobe Reader open a new window with the server version of the pdf. How can I make the Reader simply to leave the same document open and not to open anything new? If I don't send back anything, the reader crashes.

Comment: Yes, Adobe reader opens another window with the response pdf it receives. Foxit does nothing after submit. If you want to avoid returning the same pdf, return another small pdf saying your submission was successful.